# Npm install command for angular dual list box not working

Tags: angular, npm, visual-studio-code

I tried using `npm i angular-dual-listbox --save` command but getting bunch of errors stating version mismatch though i have version 8.2.14. Article used for reference: [npmjs](http://%20https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-dual-listbox/v/6.0.0). The error log is as follows:

```
C:\GUNEET KAUR\PROJ_2.0\cpd_repository\ANGULAR_CODE_BASE>npm i angular-dual-listbox --save
npm WARN @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@1.0.0-beta.6 requires a peer of @angular/core@^4.0.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@1.0.0-beta.6 requires a peer of @angular/common@^4.0.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@1.0.0-beta.6 requires a peer of @angular/forms@^4.0.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN angular-datatables@4.4.1 requires a peer of @angular/common@~4.4.6 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN angular-datatables@4.4.1 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@~4.4.6 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.npm WARN angular-datatables@4.4.1 requires a peer of @angular/core@~4.4.6 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN angular-datatables@4.4.1 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser@~4.4.6 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN angular-datatables@4.4.1 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@~4.4.6 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN angular-datatables@4.4.1 requires a peer of core-js@~2.4.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN angular-datatables@4.4.1 requires a peer of rxjs@~5.4.2 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN angular-datatables@4.4.1 requires a peer of zone.js@~0.8.16 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN angular-user-idle@2.2.4 requires a peer of @angular/common@^6.0.0 || ^10.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN angular-user-idle@2.2.4 requires a peer of @angular/core@^6.0.0 || ^10.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN bootstrap@4.0.0-beta.2 requires a peer of popper.js@^1.12.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN d3-ng2-service@1.23.3 requires a peer of @angular/core@^5.0 || ^4.0 || ^2.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ng2-popover@0.0.14 requires a peer of @angular/core@^2.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ngx-daterangepicker@2.1.0 requires a peer of @angular/common@^6.0.0-rc.0 || ^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ngx-daterangepicker@2.1.0 requires a peer of @angular/core@^6.0.0-rc.0 || ^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ngx-daterangepicker@2.1.0 requires a peer of bulma@^0.7.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ngx-daterangepicker@2.1.0 requires a peer of date-fns@^1.29.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN angular-dual-listbox@6.0.0 requires a peer of @angular/common@>=10.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN angular-dual-listbox@6.0.0 requires a peer of @angular/core@>=10.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm ERR! code E401
npm ERR! Unable to authenticate, need: Basic realm="Artifactory Realm"
```

Comment: This angular-dual-listbox needs angular version 10 or higher and none was found at your development side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to install versions 4.x for compitable with your angular version

Comment: Thanks for helping. I used `npm i angular-dual-listbox@4.7.0 --save`. Seems to work now!